# how to use gdb to debug a executable binary generated by bazel build under a linux environment

Tags: debugging, gdb, symbols, bazel

There is a simple source code hello_world.cpp, and bazel build it for debuging with gdb like this:

```
$ bazel build --cxxopt=-std=c++11 -c dbg --strip=never //examples/hello_world:hello_world
```

so I can debug it like this, and everything is going well, the source code symbols can display:

```
$ gdb bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world
Reading symbols from bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x51e9: file examples/hello_world/main.cpp, line 46.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/wss/.cache/bazel/_bazel_wss/4110822ab2eb09dee5980f588bc10e42/execroot/com_minieye_aiplorer/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe1c8) at examples/hello_world/main.cpp:46
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
46    std::cout << "WITH LINUX~~~" << std::endl;
(gdb) l
41    return 0;
42  }
43  
44  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
45  #ifdef WITH_LINUX_PC
46    std::cout << "WITH LINUX~~~" << std::endl;
47  #endif
48    if (jsonHandle(argc, argv) < 0) {
49      return -1;
50    }
```

But when I came to bazel-bin/examples/hello_world, and gdb hello-world, it'll show it as below:

```
$ cd bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/
$ gdb hello_world
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x51e9: file examples/hello_world/main.cpp, line 46.
(gdb) l
32  examples/hello_world/main.cpp: No such file or directory
(gdb) l
32  in examples/hello_world/main.cpp
```

who can tell me what happned? If I want to go on to debug under the executable binary's directory directly, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler must not be including the compilation directory into the debug information.  Instead it is just storing the relative path to the source files.  This is why you see the message:

```
examples/hello_world/main.cpp: No such file or directory
```

Without knowing the compilation directory, GDB is stuck just looking for files based on the current working directory.

However, you can help GDB out here. If you do:

```
(gdb) directory /path/to/project/directory
```

Then GDB will also look for the files within `/path/to/project/directory` -- remember, this directory should be the directory from which `examples/hello_world/main.cpp` is valid.

You can use `show directories` to see which directories GDB is using, or use `set directories` to completely rewrite the stored directory list (the `directory` command just adds a new directory to the list).

Comment: On usually,  debug a executable binary within debug symbol, it doesn't  depend on  the source code.  And more important problem is how to debug the program under a embedded enviorment?

Comment: With DWARF debug format the source code is not inserted into the executable/debug-information, all you get is the compilation directories and the source file names.  It's up to the debugger (GDB) to then find the corresponding source file and display that in order to show source code.  The debug information does contain symbol names, so things like backtraces, and printing variables will work fine with debug information but no source code.

Comment: When you ask: how to debug the program under an embedded environment, are you specifically asking about locating source code in that situation?  Or more generally?  If you are running GDB on the embedded device then this isn't really "embedded" as GDB sees it, this would just be native debug, and you'll need the source code on the target.  If you are using gdbserver or similar to remote debug an embedded device then you'll need the source code on the machine running GDB.

Comment: Build the code using cmake build with the same cross-compiler toolchains, it'll generate a binary with debug information, I don't know if it is dwarf debug format what you have metioned above, scp the binary to  target 
 embedded device, and run GDB to natively debug the program, it can display the sorce code. Now I just turn to bazel  build the same  code,  scp the newly generated binary to the device and run GDB to natively debug it ,it'll not display the source code.  I'm not sure, the device has gdbsever for a remote debug, but it real has gdb for native debug.

Comment: Your original example seemed to focus on changing the current directory though rather than building the binary using two different build systems.  You can fix the missing source after a directory change by using the `directory` command as I said.  Have you tried that?  Did it solve the problem you asked about in the original question?

Comment: sorry, set the directory fix the original question, I should give you a feedback, thanks for your answer. And I aim to ask the later question based on the original question, how to run GDB to natively debug the program on the device generared by bazel bulid through cross-copmiler toolchians and scp to the device.

Comment: If you want to natively debug on an embedded device, and you want to see the source code from GDB, then you will need the source code to be readable from the device - could copy over the source code, or network mount the directory containing the source code from the device.  If you don't want to move the source code to the device then the other option is to use gdbserver on the remote device, and connect to it from GDB on the build machine where the source code is available.

Comment: Consider the complexity of debug with gdbserver, I prefer to nativetly debug the program, and I scp the source code(only main.cpp) to the device, and set directory to the  the directory of main.cpp, and run GBD to debug, it' still cannot display the source code.

Comment: Remember the source file is recorded as `examples/hello_world/main.cpp` so GDB is going to look for that file relative to the entries in its directory list.  So if you add `/tmp` to the directories list, GDB will search for `/tmp/examples/hello_world/main.cpp` ... you'll need to build a partial source/project tree in order for GDB to find the source.

Comment: I tried a few times according to what you said, but it still cannot display the source code, the logs are below: 
`cd /app/bin
gdb ./hello_world
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40092c
(gdb) directory /app/bin/examples/hello_world
Source directories searched: /app/bin/examples/hello_world:$cdir:$cwd 
(gdb) r
Starting program: /app/bin/hello_world
Python Exception <class 'NameError'> Installation error: gdb._execute_unwinders  
function is missing: 
Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040092c in main ()
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function main.
which has no line number info...`

Comment: Well, you're getting a totally different error now: `Single stepping until exit from function main. which has no line number info` this indicates that you're trying to debug an executable without debug information.  I feel you're now moving away from the original question - you might be better off marking this question as answered, and creating a new question to describe your follow on problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andrew. Yes, it's better to create a new question.  And I've confirmed the debug info:
`$ file bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world`
bazel-bin/examples/hello_world/hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, `with debug_info, not stripped`